# iOS collapse header section in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I have a UITableView that has a header view that I want to use to display content. When no content exists, I want to hide the header view (which is a UIView class) and have the TableView Cells slide to the top of the view.

It's like

```
 ____________  
| ---------- |
| |        | |
| | header | |
| |        | |
| ---------- |
| ---------- |
| |  cell  | |
| ---------- |
|            |
```

When I call

```
[theHeaderView setHidden:YES]
```

The content in the header view disappears but the cells of my TableView remain halfway down the screen to where the header had pushed them. so i wind up with:

```
 ____________  
|            |
|   EMPTY    |
|   SPACE    |
|            |
|            |
| ---------- |
| |  cell  | |
| ---------- |
|            |
```

What is the proper way to hide the header view and have the table view cells move to the top of the screen?

and then i want to reopen my header later on with new content and push the cells down again.

thanks!

Comment: What is `theHeaderView`'s class?

Comment: the header view is a UIView

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html see this

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` rather than just making the header view hidden. I don't recall if this will animate when you reload the table (`reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`).

Comment: thanks. i tried your solution and it seems to have no effect. basically going:  [self.tableView beginUpdates]; [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; [self.tableView endUpdates]; and having tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: return 0.0f but still am left with an empty white space atop the screen. i'm probably doing something wrong! thoughts?

Comment: Are you using a table header or a section header?

Comment: ahhh it was a table header not a section header (created by dragging UIView object into storyboard and dropping above prototype cell in UITableViewController). how to handle as table header? thanks!

Comment: For a table header you could try reducing the frame height, or you might need to remove the view (set it to nil).